LocalDate to string format with HH:mm
I have a Kotlin code that retrives date (in text field) from SQLite DB and put it into a LocalDate variable (pill.startDay)  from whom I show the date as below
val dtf: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ITALY)
val startDayStr: String =dtf.format(pill.startDay)
holder.tvStartDate.text = "Start: $startDayStr"

Now I need to show also hours and minutes but I've tryed many patterns (like "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm" or "dd/MM/uuuu'T'HH:mm" or "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm z") without success (the app always crashes)
The full data class is:
data class Pill(val id: Int,
                val pillName: String,
                val yesDays: Int,
                val pauseDays: Int = 0,
                val startDay: LocalDate = LocalDate.now())

The error is:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mytestapp, PID: 24087
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported
field: HourOfDay


Please share the stacktrace from the crash.

Also, what type is pill.startDay? Fully qualified, please.

You are getting UnsupportedTemporalTypeException because you have defined your data with LocalDate.
LocalDate doesn't have any information about the time and once you are trying to convert it to time, it causes a crash.
You need to update your data class Pill to have LocalDateTime instead of LocalDate:
data class Pill(
    val id: Int,
    val pillName: String,
    val yesDays: Int,
    val pauseDays: Int = 0,
    val startDay: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
)


The reason you cannot print hours of day, minutes of hour and further down the scala is that a LocalDate exclusively stores information about day of month, month of year and year.
What you need seems to be a LocalDateTime, which is combined from a LocalDate and a LocalTime.

It took me a lot to make the code works with new type of data anyway really thanks: I would like to accept both but I can't so I've upvoted both and accepted the answer from younger member . Hope you don't mind ;)
